# replace a string with an hyperlink in a file Word powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

i want to replace a string with an hyperlink

i try with something like this

Update:

```
$FindText = "[E-mail]"
$email ="asdadasd@asdada.com"
$a=$objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText)
$newaddress = $objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add($objSelection.Range,$email) )
```

but this insert the email at beginnig of file word don't replace the string "[E-mail]"

Comment: Just to clarify: is the goal to replace the first occurrence of a text string with a mailto link inside a .docx or all instances of the text string?

Comment: in my case i have only a string = "[email]" in the .docx but the question is in general how to replace all instance of the text string

Comment: Please explain exactly *how* it "doesn't work". But FWIW Find/Replace can only work with text. A Hyperlink is an *object* so can't be used for "replace with". In you current code, remove the ReplaceWith line, then move the Hyperlinks.Add line to *after* Find.Execute. The Hyperlink will then be inserted at the "found" position.

Comment: something like this?
$FindText = "[E-mail]"
$email ="asdadasd@asdada.com"
$objSelection.Find.Text = $FindText
$newaddress = $objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add($objSelection.Range,$email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$wdunits = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdunits" -as [type]
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false
$findText = "[E-mail]"
$emailAddress = "someemail@example.com"
$mailTo = "mailto:"+$emailAddress
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("Path\to\input.docx")
$saveAs = "Path\to\output.docx")
$range = $objDoc.Content
$null = $range.movestart($wdunits::wdword,$range.start)
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection
$matchCase = $false
$matchWholeWord = $true
$matchWildcards = $false
$matchSoundsLike = $false
$matchAllWordForms = $false
$forward = $true 
$wrap = 1
$format = $False
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$wdFindContinue = 1
$wdReplaceAll = 2

$wordFound = $range.find.execute($findText,$matchCase,$matchWholeWord,$matchWildCards,$matchSoundsLike,$matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap)

if($wordFound)
{
    if ($range.style.namelocal -eq "normal")
    {
        $null = $objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add($range,$mailTo,$null,$null,$emailAddress)
    }
}

$objDoc.SaveAs($saveAs)
$objDoc.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
Remove-Variable -Name objWord
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Kinda ugly, but this script will do what you need. It loads the .docx specified with `$objDoc`, finds all instances of `$findText`, and replaces it with a mailto link for `$emailAddress` and then saves the changes to `$saveAs`.

Most of this based on a ["Hey, Scripting Guy"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/06/24/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-hyperlinks-to-a-word-document/) Article